# Cloudfoundry UUID-Url in Eureka

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, cloud-foundry

When I register an app to my Eureka on CloudFoundry, it registers itself with a UUID-style address (e.g. https://8d071e0e-681c-4218-8575-56d65ada36f3:443/). What kind of address is this? Sadly it can't be reached by other apps on cf, using this kind of address.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the following configuration to your Spring `application.yml`:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-spring-application

eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eureka-server.local.pcfdev.io/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: ${vcap.application.uris[0]:localhost}
    nonSecurePort: 80
```

This will register all instances of the app with the application URL to Eureka. Hence, the Cloud Foundry router always takes care of load balancing between app instances.
[Refer to the documentation](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/spring-cloud-netflix.html#_using_eureka_on_cloudfoundry) for more information about the options you have here.